# Как получить точные координаты мышки?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно сделать всплывающее окошко при наведении мыши на ячейку таблицы. Нашел некий скрипт, все бы ничего, но страница имеет очень большую ширину (далеко скроллится влево) и подсказка эта просто "уезжает" за пределы экрана... Вот скрипт:

```
 <script> 
 var hide = true; //глобальная переменная, отвечающая будет ли строка передана в подсказку

 function movePic(word) {
     _x = window.event.clientX;
     _y = window.event.clientY;
     _dx = 5
     left = false;
     right = false;
     if (_dx + _x + myalt.clientWidth > document.body.clientWidth) {
         _x = document.body.clientWidth - myalt.clientWidth - _dx;
         left = true;
     }
     if (_dx + _y + myalt.clientHeight > document.body.clientHeight) {
         _y = document.body.clientHeight - myalt.clientHeight - _dx;
         right = true;
     }
     if (left && right) _y = document.body.clientHeight - myalt.clientHeight - _dx * 4;
     myalt.style.left = _x;
     myalt.style.top = _y + document.body.scrollTop;
     if (hide) {
         myalt.innerHTML = word;
         myalt.style.visibility = "visible";
         hide = false;
     }
 }

 function hidePic() {
     myalt.style.visibility = "hidden";
     myalt.innerHTML = "";
     myalt.style.top = 0;
     myalt.style.left = 0;
     hide = true;
 }
 </script> 
 <head> 
 <body> 
 <div id="myalt" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; border-style:solid; border-color:'#000000'; border-width:1px; width:400px; height:10px; background-color:'#f5f5f5'; padding:3px;z-Index:3"></div> 
 <td onmousemove="movePic('Здесь текст подсказки')" onmouseout="hidePic()"> 
 </body>
```

Кстати

пришлось доработать:

```
<div id="myalt" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; border-style:dotted; border-width:1px; width:350px; height:80px; padding:3px;z-Index:3; background-image:url('img/background_window.gif')"></div>
```

`background-image:url('img/background_window.gif')` - картинка - белый пиксел, иначе ну не хочет фон непрозрачным делать!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> 
 var hide = true; //глобальная переменная, отвечающая будет ли строка передана в подсказку
 // Смотрим IE или нет.
  // если нет IE, подразумеваем что NS.
 var IE = document.all ? true : false

 // Переменные для хранения позиции мыши x-y 
 var _x = 0
 var _y = 0

 // Функция для добычи позиций мыши x-y

 function getMouseXY(e) {
     if (IE) { // если IE, то берем так
         _x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
         _y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
     } else { // если нет, так:
         _x = e.pageX
         _y = e.pageY
     }
     // эта проверка возможно уже не требуется но в NS4 нужна была
     if (_x < 0) {
         _x = 0
     }
     if (_y < 0) {
         _y = 0
     }

     return true
 }

 function movePic(word) {
     // Если NS -- значит !IE -- тогда вешаем функцию отлова мышиных передвижений 
     if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

     // Ставим на обработчик передвижений мыши функцию getMouseXY
     document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

     _dx = 5
     left = false;
     right = false;
     if (_dx + _x + myalt.clientWidth > document.body.clientWidth + document.body.scrollLeft) { // сравниваем не просто ширину, а с прокруткой
         _x = _x - myalt.clientWidth - _dx; //убираем ненужное, потому что прокрутка окна учтена в переменных _x и _y
         left = true;
     }
     if (_dx + _y + myalt.clientHeight > document.body.clientHeight + document.body.scrollTop) { // тоже по высоте
         _y = _y - myalt.clientHeight - _dx; //убираем ненужное, потому что прокрутка окна учтена в переменных _x и _y, и чтобы хинт не вылазил за пределы окна двигаем его на минус ширину и высоту этого хинта
         right = true;
     }

     if (left && right) _y = document.body.clientHeight - myalt.clientHeight - _dx * 4;
     myalt.style.left = _x + "px";
     myalt.style.top = _y + "px"; // тут без пх в хроме не работало, убрал + document.body.scrollTop, потому что он в позиции мыши учитывается уже
     if (hide) {
         myalt.innerHTML = word;
         myalt.style.visibility = "visible";
         hide = false;
     }
 }

 function hidePic() {
     myalt.style.visibility = "hidden";
     myalt.innerHTML = "";
     myalt.style.top = 0;
     myalt.style.left = 0;
     hide = true;
 }
 </script>
```

Чтобы был фон непрозрачным надо цвет писать без кавычек, вот так: background-color:#f5f5f5;

```
<div id="myalt" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;border-width:1px; width:400px;height:14px; background-color:#f5f5f5;padding:3px;z-Index:3"></div>
```

Кроссбраузерность надо тестировать.